# What is the simplest way to perform method with number of arguments on main thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch

This methon is really cool:

`- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;`

But I need something simple like it to perform method with number of arguments in main thread like:

`- (void)methodWithFirstObject: secondObject:`

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSelectorOnMainThread` is just a convenient way of playing with an `NSOperation` which is a convenient way of playing with GDC. If you ever need more functionality, just drop down to the next level. You'll have to manage a bit more complexity, but will have more flexibility. An awful lot of cocoa is designed this way.

You'll want to [read up on `NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html), but I think this will do what you want [*typing on my phone, haven't compiled*]

```
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
  [self myMethod:foo thatRequiresMultiple:bar andAlso:baz];
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object as argument.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"arg1", @"value2", @"arg2", nil];
```

pass dict in arg.

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
```

Answer (score 1):

A call to `dispatch_async()` if you want `waitUntilDone` to be `NO`, or `dispatch_sync()` for `YES`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [reciever methodWithFirstObject:obj1 secondObject:obj2];
});
```

Just be sure not to use `dispatch_sync()` if you're already on the main thread; you can test the result of `dispatch_get_current_queue()` if necessary.